# How do I check if all elements are false within a a nested forLoop and return / store answer in a variable? React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 5 x 5 table which has different coloured cells. If all the cells turn one colour then the user has "won".

table:

```
    const MainBoard = Array.from({length: this.props.nrows}).map((ignored, rowIndex) => (
      <tr>
        {Array.from({length: this.props.ncols}).map((x, cellIndex) => (
          <Cell key={`${rowIndex}-${cellIndex}`}
                isLit={this.state.board[rowIndex][cellIndex]}
                flipCellsAroundMe={() => this.flipCellsAround(`${rowIndex}-${cellIndex}`)}
          />
        ))}
      </tr>
    ));

    return (
      <table className="Board">
        <tbody>
          <h1>BOARD</h1>
          {MainBoard}
        </tbody>
      </table>

    );
  }
```

To determine whether the user has won i need to iterate over all of the cells and check if all the cells are `false`, if they are the user has won (each cell is either `true` or `false` to determine it's colour.)

I have started my iteration as follows using a `forLoop` as I desperately need to practise them:

```
    let hasWon = false;
    let myBoard = board; // this is the 5x5 table i'm iterating over

    for(let i = 0; i < myBoard.length; i ++){ // looping over board rows
      for(let j = 0; j < myBoard.length; j ++){ // looping over each cell in each row
          let boardCells = myBoard[j]; // this returns an array of `true` or `false` cells 



     (How do i check here if all the cells are false and return the answer so i can store it 
      in the `hasWon` variable above?)



      }
    }

    this.setState({
      board: board,
      hasWon: hasWon
    });
  }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't use the `i` variable in your nested loop.  Is `myBoard` a flat array or is it an array of arrays?  Either you need to reference `myBoard[j][i]` for an array of arrays or `myBoard[j*myBoard.length+i]` for a flat array.

Comment: Regarding your original question, maybe start with the simple case of how would you determine all are false for 2 boolean variables, then 3 boolean variables, then try to extrapolate that to the nested loop.

Comment: @IanWilson `myBoard` is an array of arrays : `(5) [Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5), Array(5)]
0: (5) [false, false, true, true, true]
1: (5) [true, false, false, false, true]
2: (5) [false, false, false, false, false]
3: (5) [false, true, false, false, false]
4: (5) [false, false, true, false, false]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
const matrix = [
    [false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false],
];
let won = true;
for(let i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
    if(!won) {
        break;
    }
    for( let j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
        if(matrix[i][j]) {
            won = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(won);
```

With goto (labels) will be even faster but it is anti-pattern.

```
const matrix = [
    [false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false, true],
];

function hasWon(matrix) {
    let won = true;
    loops: for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j]) {
                won = false;
                break loops;
            }
        }
    }
    return won;
}

console.log(hasWon(matrix));
```

Or you can use very short way:

```
const won = matrix.join().indexOf('true') === -1
```

Comment: this works and is what i wanted but I have too look at it properly and see how and why!

Comment: Why are you checking if won is false in the first loop? @ArthurRubens

Comment: As soon as I find a "true" value I go out from the second loop, after that I must go out from the first one. That is why I check it.
To avoid this checks you can use while() controlling or even goto. The last one is the fastest way.

Comment: OK thank you the explanation and code helps I will write this down :)

Answer (score 0):

Like summation in math, the and (`&&`) has the associative and commutative property.

What this means is that if you repeatedly update your `hasWon` in a loop doing something like `hasWon = hasWon && !cellValue`, it will produce the same result as checking if every single cell is false.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know in what context ur using this but I have done something like this before. Basically you are generating output but you have no way to see the state of the cells, right?
What I would do in this situation would be add an event handler (probably onClick) like this :

```
onclick(e){
let idOfElement = e.target.id;
let anyOtherAttribute = e.target.*anyOtherAtrribute*
}
```

this other attribute can be a prop of 's

You can use this. If you didnt understand this answer feel free to comment down below so I can help out

Comment: Hey, I know the state of the cells by `console.logging` them but I just needed to loop over all the cells and return whether they were all `false` if call of the cells were equal to false then the user has won the game!

Comment: Oh its like a those things in the casinos in the movies. For colours.